# Why click on FCM notification in tray not launched my app?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

My notification data message is as below:

```
{data=
    {"sender_username":null,
        "image":null,
        "is_background":false,
        "payload":{"post_id":"1"},
        "userId":2,
        "title":"ABC",
        "message":"Someone liked your post!",
        "timestamp":"2018-06-02 10:46:50"
    }
}
```

This message is received when app is in foreground,it received in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)`.I also know that my this message is only received when app in foreground.

**Problem**

But when the app in background or closed,the notification is appear in notification tray.The problem is when I click on the notification,it doesn't launch my app,totally no response.

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Firebase service -->
     <service
        android:name=".services.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".services.FirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Here is how I handle the notification:

```
public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.drawable.logo;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (!imageUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(null) && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}

private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(AppConfig.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

My code run well before in `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'`,the problem happen when I upgrade to `'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'`.

After I looking at the same code again and again for past 2 days,I still cant figure out,where the problem came from.Somebody please help..

If possible,please give some hint about what is the possible issue that will cause this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can give a better idea if you can tell me From where you are calling this showNotification message, and where is your FirebaseMessagingService() class ?

But as far as i understand, the intent you are passing as parameter should specify which activity you want to open, something like this:

```
    val intent = Intent(this@MyFirebaseMessagingService, MainActivity::class.java)// here i want to open the MainActivity on notification click
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@MyFirebaseMessagingService, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

I will get a clear view if you can show me your class where you are extending FirebaseMessagingService() class.

Hope it helps.